# How can we extend Saturn OAuth's authentication cookie expiration to last longer than a session?

Tags: cookies, oauth, f#, saturn-framework

We are using Saturn's Authorization extension to allow for authorization with Azure and Google. The Saturn configuration options that we use are `use_azuread_oauth_with_config` and `use_google_oauth`. The problem that we are facing is that the cookies used to store a user's authorization token lasts for only a session. We would, however, like this cookie to last for a set time period, such as 2 weeks, so that the user does not have to log in every time they begin a session.

What we have tried is to use the field in the OAuth configuration, `input.CorrelationCookie.Expiration`, as well as the field `input.CorrelationCookie.MaxAge`, so that the configuration looks something like the following:

```
let azureOAuthOptions (input : OAuthOptions) =
   input.CallbackPath <- PathString("/microsoftCallback")
   input.TokenEndpoint <- "..."
   input.ClientId <- "..."
   input.ClientSecret <- "..."
   input.UsePkce <- true
   input.SaveTokens <- true
   input.CorrelationCookie.SameSite <- SameSiteMode.Lax
   input.CorrelationCookie.Expiration <- TimeSpan.FromDays(14.0) // here is where we tried to extend the expiration to beyond a session
   input.CorrelationCookie.MaxAge <- TimeSpan.FromDays(14.0) // and here
   input.AuthorizationEndpoint <- "..."

   ()
```

And then we used the configuration as following: `use_azuread_oauth_with_config azureOAuthOptions`

Unfortunately this did not work and the token cookie (set as the cookie named `.AspNetCore.Cookies`) still last only as long as a session, although we tried to make it last for 14 days. How can we cause the cookie to last for beyond a session.